# Probability that exactly $k$ balls in each group are black and rest are white

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Assume that we have a total of $n$ balls, $b$ of which are black and the remaining are white. I want to partition them into $g$ groups of size $r$ (i.e., $n=g \times r$) such that for $b/k$ of the groups exactly $k$ balls in each group are black; the rest of groups have only white balls. I want to compute the probability of this happening if one was to pick the balls for the groups at random (without replacement). For the purposes of this problem you can assume that $k$ divides $b$.

My thinking is that we can imagine we have two bags (one with blacks of size $b$ and another with whites) and that we start populating groups one by one and keeping track of the remaining balls of each bag such that the probability is

$$\frac{{b \choose k}{n-b \choose r-k} \times {b-k \choose k}{n-b-(r-k) \choose r-k} \times \cdots \times {b-(b/k-1)k \choose k}{n-b-(b/k-1)(r-k) \choose r-k}}{{n \choose r}}$$

i.e., we stop at the last mixed group since for the last group there are no black balls left.

Is this calculation correct?

I think the denominator is wrong, I think it might be ${n \choose k}$ (which is equal to all possible orderings of the balls in a line) but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are calculating a probability, we can safely assume the $g$ groups are distinguishable, and that the balls are distinguishable. With this formulation, the sample space is simply the set of all assignments of the $n$ balls to the $g$ groups such that each group gets $r$ balls, and this can be done in $\binom{n}{r;r;\cdots;r}$, the multinomial coefficient with $g$ copies of $r$ at bottom.

For the event you are considering, the first thing you need to do is pick $\frac{b}{k}$ of the groups to get the black balls, which can be done in $\binom{g}{b/k}$ ways (this is a key factor missing in your analysis). Then there are $\binom{b}{k;k;\cdots;k}$ ($\frac{b}{k}$ $k$'s in the bottom) ways to distribute the black balls to these bins. Finally you must distribute the white balls. Each of the bins with black balls must get $r-k$ white balls, while the remaining bins must get $r$ white balls; this assignment can be done in $\binom{n-b}{r-k;r-k;\cdots;r-k;r;r;\cdots;r}$ (there are $\frac{b}{k}$ $r-k$'s and $g-\frac{b}{k}$ $r$'s on the bottom). The probability you need is the product of these three quantities, divided by the size of the sample space.

EDIT: In comment, the OP asks a slight extension where the desired condition is that $\lfloor\frac{b}{k}\rfloor$ bins (let's call them "special") contain exactly $k$ black balls, and the remaining black balls can be distributed arbitrarily. In this case the analysis is a bit more complex, but follows the same logic. There are $\binom{g}{\lfloor b/k\rfloor}$ ways to pick the bins that get $k$ black balls, and then $$\binom{b}{k;k;\cdots;k;b-k\lfloor b/k\rfloor}$$ to pick the $k\lfloor b/k\rfloor$ black balls that will go in the special bins and distribute them. The $b-k\lfloor b/k\rfloor$ selects the black balls that will later be distributed to the non-special bins.

The next task is to fill up the special bins with white balls, so we can make sure we don't get any additional black balls in. This can be done in $$\binom{n-b}{r-k;r-k;\cdots;r-k;n-b-(r-k)\lfloor b/k\rfloor}$$ ways. As with the black balls, we are both picking which white balls will go in the special bins and distributing them...the distribution of the white balls to non-special bins is left until later.

Finally, we need to distribute the remaining balls to the non-special bins, regardless of whether they are black or white. This can be done in $$\binom{n-r\lfloor b/k\rfloor}{r;r;\cdots;r}$$ where there are $g-\lfloor b/k\rfloor$ $r$'s on the bottom (correction provided by OP).

Note: you pretty much have to do the counts in this order, because you don't have any control on the black/white distribution in the non-special bins.

Comment: Oh, got it. How would this change if $k$ does not divide $b$ and we want $\lfloor \frac{b}{k} \rfloor$ groups to have this property (the maximum number of groups that this can happen) and the leftover black balls to be in any arrangement in the other groups. Is this a completely different task?

Comment: No, it's pretty much the same. Will edit answer to show how.

Comment: @mgus: Answered your question with further explanation. Short answer: it's basically the same, just a little more intricate.

Comment: Are you sure that the number of $r$'s at the bottom of the last multinomial coefficient is $n-\lfloor b/k\rfloor$ and not $g-\lfloor b/k\rfloor$? Can you please explain?

Comment: @mgus: You are correct. The number of $r$'s should be $g-\lfloor b/k\rfloor$. A lot of letters floating around and I was typing late. Will fix.

Answer (score 0):

When $b/k$ is an integer value, you seek the probability for obtaining $k$ black balls placed among the $r$ balls in each of $b/k$ from $g$ groups (leaving no black balls to place elsewhere), when selecting where to place $b$ black balls among the $n$ balls.$$\dfrac{\dbinom{r}{k}^{b/k}\dbinom{g}{b/k}}{\dbinom{n}{k}}$$

Now should $b/k$ not be an integer, then we wish each from $\lfloor b/k\rfloor$ to receive $k$ black balls there will be a remainder of $(b-k\lfloor b/k\rfloor)$ black balls to place among the remaining $g-\lfloor b/k\rfloor$ groups of size $r$.  We shall not want more than $\lfloor b/k\rfloor$ to receive exactly $k$ black balls, so the principle of inclusion and exclusion may be required for some values of $k, b$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this solution is not giving a valid probability. Try $r=5$, $k=3$, $b=12$, $n=25$.